# NGRX Effect withLatestFrom Typescript error ts2345 troubleshooting

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, ngrx

I'm not sure how to continue troubleshooting this ts2345 error and could use some help with understanding its cause.

Error Detail

> Argument of type '(source$: Observable) => Observable' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction'.
>
> Types of parameters 'source$' and 'source' are incompatible.
>
> import("c:/Users/Flignats/Documents/GitHub/reqloot/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Observable").Observable' is not assignable to type 'import("c:/Users/Flignats/Documents/GitHub/reqloot/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Observable").Observable'.
>
> Property 'user' is missing in type 'import("c:/Users/Flignats/Documents/GitHub/reqloot/src/app/modules/guilds/guilds.state").State' but required in type 'import("c:/Users/Flignats/Documents/GitHub/reqloot/src/app/modules/user/user.state").State'.ts(2345)
>
> user.state.ts(19, 3): 'user' is declared here.

This is my effect file in the 'guilds' feature

guilds.effects.ts

```
import { IPrivateGuildDetails } from './guilds.model';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { select, Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import { ROUTER_NAVIGATION, RouterNavigationAction } from '@ngrx/router-store';
import { Actions, ofType, createEffect } from '@ngrx/effects';
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import {
    map,
    mergeMap,
    catchError,
    withLatestFrom,
    switchMap,
    tap,
    filter
} from 'rxjs/operators';
// Core
import * as fromCore from '../../core';
import * as fromAuth from '../../core/auth/auth.selectors';
import * as fromUser from '../user/user.selectors';
// Key
export const GUILDS_KEY = 'GUILDS';
// State
import { State, selectGuilds } from './guilds.state';
// Actions
import {
    createGuild,
    createGuildSuccess,
    createGuildFailure,
    loadPublicGuilds,
    loadPublicGuildsSuccess,
    loadPublicGuildsFailure,
    loadTriggerStatusCreateGuild,
    loadTriggerStatusCreateGuildFailure,
    loadTriggerStatusCreateGuildSuccess,
    selectPublicGuild,
    loadPublicGuild,
    loadPublicGuildSuccess,
    loadPublicGuildFailure,
    loadMyGuild,
    loadMyGuildSuccess,
    loadMyGuildFailure
} from './guilds.actions';

@Injectable()
export class GuildsEffects {
    loadMyGuild$ = createEffect(() =>
        this.actions$.pipe(
            ofType(loadMyGuild),
            withLatestFrom(this.store.pipe(select(fromUser.selectUserAccountDetails))),
            switchMap(([action, user]) =>
                this.afs.loadMyGuild(user).pipe(
                    map((result: IPrivateGuildDetails) => loadMyGuildSuccess({ myGuild: result })),
                    catchError(error => of(loadMyGuildFailure({ error })))
                )
            )
        )
    );

    loadTriggerStatusCreateGuild$ = createEffect(() =>
        this.actions$.pipe(
            ofType(loadTriggerStatusCreateGuild),
            withLatestFrom(this.store.pipe(select(fromAuth.selectUid))),
            mergeMap(([action, uid]) =>
                this.afs.getTriggerStatusCreateNewGuild(uid).pipe(
                    map(triggerStatus =>
                        loadTriggerStatusCreateGuildSuccess({ triggerStatus })
                    ),
                    catchError(error =>
                        of(loadTriggerStatusCreateGuildFailure({ error }))
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    );

  constructor(
    private actions$: Actions,
    private afs: fromCore.FirestoreService,
    private localStorageService: fromCore.LocalStorageService,
    private router: Router,
    private store: Store<State>
  ) {}
    }
```

guilds.state.ts

```
import { ActionReducerMap, createFeatureSelector } from '@ngrx/store';
import { AppState } from '@app/core';

import { guildsReducer } from './guilds.reducer';
import { GuildsStateDetails } from './guilds.model';

export const FEATURE_NAME = 'guilds';

export interface GuildsState {
  state: GuildsStateDetails;
};

export const reducers: ActionReducerMap<GuildsState> = {
  state: guildsReducer
};

export const selectGuilds = createFeatureSelector<State, GuildsState>(FEATURE_NAME);

export interface State extends AppState {
  guilds: GuildsState;
};
```

The error is produced in the `loadMyGuild$` withLatestFrom select fn

The `loadTriggerStatusCreateGuild$` effect is using a select from the core module and it does not produce an error.

If I update the `loadMyGuild$` withLatestFrom selector with a selector from the `Guilds` module, i.e. `selectGuilds` there is no error.

I'm unsure what could be different in the `User` feature module that is causing this error when trying to use its selectors in the `Guilds` feature module.

user.state.ts

```
import { ActionReducerMap, createFeatureSelector } from '@ngrx/store';
import { AppState } from '@app/core';

import { userReducer } from './user.reducer';
import { UserStateDetails } from './user.model';

export const FEATURE_NAME = 'user';
export const selectUser = createFeatureSelector<State, UserState>(FEATURE_NAME);

export const reducers: ActionReducerMap<UserState> = {
  state: userReducer
};

export interface UserState {
  state: UserStateDetails;
}

export interface State extends AppState {
  user: UserState;
}
```

user.selectors.ts

```
import { createSelector } from '@ngrx/store';

import { UserState, selectUser } from './user.state';

export const selectActiveUser = createSelector(
  selectUser,
  (state: UserState) => state.state
);

export const selectUserAccountDetails = createSelector(
  selectUser,
  (state: UserState) => state.state.account
);

export const selectUserLoading = createSelector(
  selectUser,
  (state: UserState) => state.state.loading
);

export const selectUserError = createSelector(
  selectUser,
  (state: UserState) => state.state.error
);
```

user.model.ts

```
import { HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Timestamp } from '@firebase/firestore-types';

export interface IUser {
  applixir?: {
    lastWatchedAt?: Timestamp;
    staminaLastGiven?: Timestamp;
    totalAdsWatched?: number;
    totalStaminaCollected?: number;
    currentAdsTrackedCount: number;
  };
  balance: {
    claimed: number;
    unclaimed: number;
  };
  createdAt: Timestamp;
  displayName?: string;
  email: string;
  fcmTokens?: { [token: string]: true };
  guildDetails?: {
    attacks: { [key: string]: number };
    boosts: { [key: string]: { [key: string]: number } };
    guildId: string;
    guildTokensCollected: number;
    guildTokensCollectedCount: number;
    shield: { [key: string]: number };
  };
  referredBy?: string;
  referredAt?: Timestamp;
  stamina: number;
  staminaLastGiven?: Timestamp;
  subscriberStamina?: number;
  subscriberStaminaLastGiven?: Timestamp;
  uid: string;
  updatedAt?: Timestamp;
}

export interface UserStateDetails {
  error: HttpErrorResponse | string;
  loading: boolean;

  account: IUser;
}
```

Comment: Where do you inject services in your effects?

Comment: @Yevgeniy.ChernobrivetsUpdated the guilds.effects.ts with its constructor and added the guilds.state.ts code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using wrong store - you injected in your effects `Store<State>` where `State` is guild state and of course user selectors won't work on it. You need to inject Store with User state and use it instead.

Comment: That was it! I thought that since the guild state extended the AppState that it would have been accessible - but I guess not